# IntelliJ Android SDK doesn't find JDK

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sdk, jdk1.7

I've installed Android Studio and then installed a couple of Android SDKs from the SDK Manager. Then installed JDK7 but when I try to attach Android SDK It give this error. Pic 1, 2, 3 and 4 are the things I do to include android sdk in IntelliJ.

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIBqp.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjx4h.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndRk3.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSRPu.png
```

Comment: Since stackoverflow recognises these links as code snippets I had to put them in code block.

Comment: Note that Android Studio 3.x now supports JDK 8, https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support So I'm wondering if its a combination of the plugin / latest SDK.

Comment: Yes i am aware that it works with JDK 8, but when i include JDK8 it gives me the option to choose between Android 24 and 27 even  though i have about 6 more SDKs. I had to use Android SDK 23.